# How do I remove a collector box from a rheem furnace

Tags: hvac

I had some water backup through the condensate drain and it got into my collector box.  I wanted to pull it off so that I can clean it out, remove the water and disinfect but I can't seem to remove it after pulling out the screws.  Is there an adhesive or something that is holding it on?

Note that the picture has the screws in, but I have removed the screws and tried pulling it off but no luck.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It might have a sealer/gasket.  Are you sure you are moving it the right direction.  Looks like it is behind the aluminum frame on the sides.  Check for hidden screws.

Comment: it looks like there is a gasket but not sure why it would be so strong - it doesn't seem to even shimmy at all when I shake it  - it's on rock solid with no movement whatsoever.  Looking for a hidden screw somewhere but I don't see anything, - it wouldn't be a screw from the other side at all right?

Comment: got it off - I just had to muscle it and seems like there was some adhesion

Comment: Gaskets tend to get sticky, even if no adhesive was used to mount them.  They are usually a one time use only and need to be replaced when removed.

Comment: Please post and accept a self-answer so this question isn't floating around for years unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So all it took was a lot of force.   Removing the screws was enough and I just needed to pull against the adhesive and it popped right off.